# Как из словаря создать список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, списки, словари

Только изучаю Python. Скажите, пожалуйста, как из словаря `{'a':['b','c'], 'd':['e', 'f']}`сделать список `[['a', 'b','c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]`?

Comment: `[[k] + v for k, v in словарь.items()]`

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое

Comment: @andreymal: это может вывести: `[['d', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]`